# How much food can an average person eat, and which animal is that equivalent to?

Tags: food

When the average person **overeats**, how much food can he eat in a day? Which animal's average meal would that be equivalent to?

When documentaries are talking about animals feed, they usually say something like "The fish can eat 500kg of prawns in a day!" But when it comes to humans, they calculate in calories. Which animals are we closest to in terms of capacity?

Note: I think I can be slightly loose on the definition of overeating here. It can mean eating beyond the point of feeling full, or the human maximum stomach capacity.